# Hide GameObjects to speed up game performance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is, how could I hide a `GameObject` when it is not being rendered by the camera, but to unhide it when it comes back into the camera view?

My code is the following:

```
void Update () {
     if (renderer.isVisible) {
         objectToHide.renderer.enabled = true;
     }
     else {
         objectToHide.renderer.enabled = false;
     }
}
```

The problem is, the object becomes hidden, so it can't be detected and unhidden.

Any help is appreciated!

(The goal is simply to speed up the FPS and improve game performance)

Comment: This question is too vague for the format of this site. You would need to keep track of all objects at some level and do the work to check if they are in the frame somewhere, like some physics thread. Just because an object isn't visible doesn't mean it stops moving.

Comment: there is OnBecameVisible callback, but it make no sense. If object isn't seen by any camera it won't be used for rendering at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is simple. The game only renders the objects in camera sight. You can hide an object or even disable the renderer component but its not used for memory management or better process.

There are standard techniques for making a game run more effient. One of them is **LOD** or **LEVEL OF DETAIL**. You have a model with different polycounts and different texture resolution. When its near you use the highest polycound and highest texture resolution for further distance you use lower options.

Another technique is **level streaming**. If you have a big level and you want to game run on low memory or don't make players wait for long time for level loading, you have to do this. If you search a little you can find lots of information on different engines.

Most recent games have an option to choose foliage detail or environment detail. You can make a layer for every level of detail of your game and for every level of option player made you destroy those objects. Maybe I'm wrong but **renderer.enable** cant be good because the object still is in game and game just doesn't show it. You have to change many components to make it work and controlling all of them is hard.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, you better try to destroy scripts and gameobjects as soon as they are not needed. Like bullets coming out of the game board, scripts that run just once and already finished, ...